# How to display images with a fade in effect in a listview?

Tags: android, imageview

How is it possible to display images with a fade in effect (i don't know the exact name) in a listview like the app yummly doing.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yummly.android
Any reference to such libraries or helpful resources?

Comment: do you mean animation effect?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example

In adapter(extend BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter):

```
private int lastPosition = -1;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  //.....inflating and bind view

  setAnimation(convertView, position);
  return convertView;
}


 /**
 * Here is the key method to apply the animation
 */
private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
    // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
    if (position > lastPosition) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.fade_in);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}
```

Or for RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final HistoryHolder holder, final int position) {
....
setAnimation(holder.animatedView, position);
}
```